# uwebsockets failed to start: libuv.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `uv_is_closing'

Tags: c++, libuv, uwebsockets

My project has linked uwebsockets.
**linked libs:**

```
C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/_/_/package/a955db98e980a5ab86ae50d6df8bfee361185c27/lib/libzlib.a;
C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/libuv/1.41.0/_/_/package/a955db98e980a5ab86ae50d6df8bfee361185c27/lib/libuv_a.a;
C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a;
iphlpapi.dll;psapi.dll;userenv.dll;ws2_32.dll
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"

int main()
{
  uWS::App().get("/hello", [](auto *res, auto *req) {
      res->end("Hello");
    });
  std::cout << "exiting now!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I got errors

```
libuv.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `uv_is_closing'
libuv.c:-1: error: undefined reference to `uv_poll_init_socket'
……
```

35 functions was undefined, but I cant call these functions in my main.cpp directly.

os: Windows10 x64

IDE: QtCreator4.14.2

compiler: MinGW 32-bit

full of the error log

> 11:04:53: 为项目rfid-cmd执行步骤 ... 11:04:53: 正在启动
> "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --target all
>
> [1/1 0.3/sec] Linking CXX executable rfid-cmd.exe FAILED: rfid-cmd.exe
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\bin\g++.exe -g
> CMakeFiles/rfid-cmd.dir/main.cpp.obj -o rfid-cmd.exe
> -Wl,--out-implib,librfid-cmd.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LD:/Project/misc/qt/rfid-cmd/lib   -LD:/Project/misc/qt/rfid-cmd/lib/NFC9 -lReader  -lEasyUSB214x  C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/*/*/package/a955db98e980a5ab86ae50d6df8bfee361185c27/lib/libzlib.a
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/libuv/1.41.0/*/*/package/a955db98e980a5ab86ae50d6df8bfee361185c27/lib/libuv_a.a  C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a  -liphlpapi  -lpsapi  -luserenv  -lws2_32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0xce):
> undefined reference to `uv_is_closing' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x143): undefined reference to` uv_poll_init_socket'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x1ee):
> undefined reference to `uv_poll_stop' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to` uv_prepare_init'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x2dc):
> undefined reference to `uv_prepare_start' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x2e7): undefined reference to` uv_unref'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x30a):
> undefined reference to `uv_check_init' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to` uv_unref'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x328):
> undefined reference to `uv_check_start' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x371): undefined reference to` uv_loop_new'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x38f):
> undefined reference to `uv_ref' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x39a): undefined reference to` uv_prepare_stop'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x3af):
> undefined reference to `uv_close' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x3ba): undefined reference to` uv_ref'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x3c5):
> undefined reference to `uv_check_stop' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to` uv_close'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x40f):
> undefined reference to `uv_run' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x41a): undefined reference to` uv_loop_delete'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x44f):
> undefined reference to `uv_run' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x4f3): undefined reference to` uv_timer_init'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x514):
> undefined reference to `uv_unref' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x550): undefined reference to` uv_ref'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x558):
> undefined reference to `uv_timer_stop' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x56b): undefined reference to` uv_close'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x5d2):
> undefined reference to `uv_timer_start' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x620): undefined reference to` uv_ref'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x633):
> undefined reference to `uv_close' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x669): undefined reference to` uv_async_init'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x671):
> undefined reference to `uv_unref' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to` uv_poll_start'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x1cf):
> undefined reference to `uv_poll_start' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to` uv_close'
> C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/*/*/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x5a7):
> undefined reference to `uv_timer_stop' C:/Users/Sunway/.conan/data/usockets/0.7.1/_/_/package/c8f7ac6f549a378a4f5ea4f08b4f33a70398fa20/lib/libuSockets.a(libuv.o):libuv.c:(.text+0x686): undefined reference to` uv_async_send' collect2.exe: error: ld
> returned 1 exit status ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 11:04:58: 进程"C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe"退出，退出代码 1 。 Error
> while building/deploying project rfid-cmd (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2
> MinGW 32-bit) When executing step "Build" 11:04:58: Elapsed time:
> 00:05.

Comment: Could you please paste more error logs? The logs seem you have added the `libuv.c` into your project.

Comment: Is there any linking sequence problem? I see that usockets links behind libuv, maybe we can try swap the sequence: to link usockets first.

Comment: the correct sequence: libuSockets.a; libuv_a.a; iphlpapi.dll;psapi.dll;userenv.dll;ws2_32.dll; libzlib.a

Comment: Glad to hear that! Then you may accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any linking sequence problem? I see that `usockets` links behind `libuv`, maybe we can try swap the sequence: to link `usockets` first.

You are using static linkage, and `usockets` depends on `libuv`, so swap the sequence will fix the problem.

Related questions:

[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)